# Regular expression to extract file name from perforce path

Tags: regex, perforce

A perforce depot path is of the following format:

> //depot/solution/project/file.cs#232

How can I extract just the "file.cs". I have tried the following.

```
[^//]*$
```

Not sure how to eliminate "#1" part. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will find file names even if they don't have a # after them.

```
(\w+\.\w+)[^/]*$
```

**Explanation:**

`(\w+\.\w+)`

This matches the file name itself, `\w` is a word character (same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). So its 1+ word character, a full stop (`.` on its own matches any character, you need `\.` to match an actual `.`), then 1+ more word characters.

`[^/]*`

Matches 0+ characters that are not `/`. But all the word characters will get put into the `\w+` match before (because it is evaluated first and `+` will try to match as much as it can) so in your example this matches the `#200`

`$`

matches the end of the line. Which is needed so `a.directory` wouldn't get matched in `/a.directory/file.txt`

Comment: use matched group 1 for just the file name

Comment: Thanks! group 1 works for my needs. Do you mind explaining it in a sentence? I am trying to learn regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/\/([^\/#]*)#/
```

And use matched group #1 for your value `file.cs`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), you can use the pattern:

```
'[^/]*(?=#)'
```